# What does "Upload Symbol Files" in regards to the Facebook Parse framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6

I am setting up crash analytics with Parse and this one of the instructions. Do I have to do this step? What does it even mean?

I ask because this step actually causes my build to fail. If I don't do this step, I can build and launch with the test crash, but the crashes never show up in my Parse dashboard -- I suspect it is because I haven't done this step. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dSYM files are "debug symbols", the stuff that allows you to make sense of crash reports. Without these files, crash reports are just lists of memory addresses without useful names associated with them so you can see where your app crashes.

Parse should be getting crashes from your app regardless of this information though I'm not sure if they show crash reports which can't be symbolicated because they lack a dSYM file. If they do show you unsymbolicated crashes, you can download them and symbolicate the crashes locally.

Comment: That helps a lot; thanks. You're right about it just showing memory addresses. Additionally, I think I wasn't getting the crashes because I was testing the app offline.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, I now know that Parse needs a while, maybe even up to a day, to get the first crash reports in. There is a delay at first. As well, as was stated by Nick, the symbol files are important for proper readability.

In my case, I was using an existing project and the build was failing because the file path to the parse folder was incorrect. I fixed the issue by simply dragging the parse folder into my project folder and then properly linking to it in the script. It now builds.